# Trying to show data from a rest api which exports in csv?

Tags: angular, rest, csv

When i'm trying to show the data via the console, i't dons't show anything. I get the message undefined.
I´m using angular

This is my service class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
{HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {any} from 'codelyzer/util/function';

const url = environment.apiEndpoint;

@Injectable()
export class CheckInService {

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

getCheckedToday(): Observable<string[]> {
return this.http.get<string[]>(url + '&id=37' + '&exportformat=csv');
}
}
```

This is my component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CheckInService} from './check-in.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-check-in',
templateUrl: './check-in.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./check-in.component.css']
})
export class CheckInComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private checkinSerivce: CheckInService   ) { }

checkInArray: string[];
ngOnInit() {

this.checkinSerivce.getCheckedToday().subscribe(
  data => (
    this.checkInArray = data
  )
);
console.log(this.checkInArray);
```

}
  }

[my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8UUP.png)

Comment: put console inside the subscribe block

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I have updated your code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CheckInService} from './check-in.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-check-in',
templateUrl: './check-in.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./check-in.component.css']
})
export class CheckInComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private checkinSerivce: CheckInService   ) { }

checkInArray: string[];
ngOnInit() {


this.checkinSerivce.getCheckedToday().subscribe(
  data => {
    this.checkInArray = data;
  }, err => {
   console.log('error loading data', err);
 }
);
console.log(this.checkInArray);
```

I suspect that the problem was that the `this.checkInArray = data;` was wrapped in round brackets. Let me know, if it helped

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I tried your code. I got the error message "error loading" and the undefined.

Comment: Then the problem is probably on server. Inspect the network tab

Comment: No server is working. I Can se that i have a lot of information inside

Comment: I mean the "network tab" in "dev tools" of your browser. Should be available by pressing F12

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to an Observable is an asynchronous function call. You have to put your execution code inside the subscription.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CheckInService} from './check-in.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-check-in',
  templateUrl: './check-in.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./check-in.component.css']
})
export class CheckInComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private checkinSerivce: CheckInService   ) { }

  checkInArray: string[];
  
  ngOnInit() {

    this.checkinSerivce.getCheckedToday().subscribe(
      data => { // <- curly bracket here
        this.checkInArray = data;
        console.log(this.checkInArray); // <-- put your code here
      } // <- curly bracket here
    );
    console.log(this.checkInArray); // <-- this is undefined, because the subscription from the observable is fired asynchronously
  }
 }
```

Comment: I updated my answer: You have to use curly brackets when using arrow functions with multiple statements:     this.checkinSerivce.getCheckedToday().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.checkInArray = data;
        console.log(this.checkInArray); // <-- put your code here
      }
    );

Comment: After implementing your code, I don´t get the undefined message, but the console dosen't print any information out?
And thank for the replay by the way